# Check all file inputs for content

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to cycle through all file inputs with the class of .ruFileInput each time there is a change to one of the inputs.

If they are all filled I would like to do something - in this example alert("No Empty Fields!!");

The issue is that the message pops every time a file input changes instead of alerting once they are all filled. Any suggestions?

```
$('input.ruFileInput').live('change' , function () { 
    $("input.ruFileInput").each(function() {
        if($(this).val() != ""){
            alert("No Empty Fields!!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Make sure to get rid of `live`.

Comment: The original answer I went with was removed for some reason. Using that answer and the suggestion from @gdoron of removing live I ended up with:`$('.uploadcontrolx').on('change', 'input.ruFileInput', function () { 
           var x = $("input.ruFileInput").filter(function(){
               return $.trim(this.value) == ''
           }).length;
         
           if(x == 0){
              alert('no empty boxes');
           }
         });`

Answer (score 1):

```
var doesEmptyExist = $("input.ruFileInput").filter(function(){
    return this.value === "";
}).length > 0;
```

Note `live` is deprecated since 1.7 **and was removed in 1.9**, stop using it!

```
$('#containerId').on('change', 'input.ruFileInput', function(){
    var doesEmptyExist = $("input.ruFileInput").filter(function(){
        return this.value === "";
    }).length > 0;

    if (!doesEmptyExist)
        alert('no empty boxes');
});
```

Comment: Anyone care to run a speed test between this and my answer? I'm curious to see if pure jQuery selectors are always faster or not. This should be pretty fast. +1 for not turning `this` into a jQuery object simply to check the value like some other people :P

Answer (score 1):

Simply with the jQuery selector:

```
if ($('input.ruFileInput[value=""]').length == 0) {
    alert("No empty Fields");
}
```

Comment: Just make sure to trim the values beforehand.

Comment: If he has to trim the values, then they aren't actually empty, are they? I mean, how do they end up with white space if a file path wasn't selected?

Comment: I agree. Not likely in the case of file input. But as a general rule of thumb, as this may apply to any input element.

Comment: I won't downvote, but it's wrong, you shouldn't use attribute selector for value, it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Selector attribute for value absolutely does work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a **boolean value** instead of alerting in the `.each` loop.

```
$('input.ruFileInput').live('change', function () {
    var isEmpty = false;
    $("input.ruFileInput").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            isEmpty = true;
            break;
        }
    });
    if (!isEmpty) {
        alert("No Empty Fields!!");
    }
});
```